# I am programming Pig script. Need to add three columns in a unstructured file.

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a unstructured  key value pair file with with 19-22 columns. The file has 8000 records.1st 4000 records having 19 columns and the other records have 22 columns.Seeing the 2nd 4000 records I got to know where the position and names of the missing 3 columns from  top 4000. Col1 should be in 3rd position and the col2 and col4 to the last position of the record. Can you please help me how do I start and resolve it.So that the output file contains a structured total of 22 columns each and it should only have the values from the columns but not the key of it.

Comment: Are the records delimited in any way? Tabs, commas, other?

Comment: Could you provide sample of your data? It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a custom pig loader. You parse the data and then you can definie your own schema to manage the missing columns